# Unable to get actual likes of Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I use

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fiatNL
```

to check the page likes of the Dutch Fiat Facebook page. The likes that are displayed are the combined likes of all Fiat Facebook pages together (over 1 million). I know that the Dutch Fiat page has no more than 50k likes.

If I check the brand children with this query:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fiat%3Ffields%3Dglobal_brand_children.fields(name%2Clikes)
```

It still shows the combined likes. 
Is there a way to check the likes of each brand child seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible because **if you likes the page at https://www.facebook.com/fiatnl/, you're automatically likes the other page at https://www.facebook.com/fiatdk/ too**.

This pages likes is sync:

[image]

[image]

If you unlikes the page at https://www.facebook.com/fiatnl/, the other page at https://www.facebook.com/fiatdk/ become unlike too.

**Update:**

You can try to request (110630838997361 is the page id of http://www.facebook.com/fiatnl):

> SELECT value FROM insights where object_id='110630838997361' and
>   metric='page_fans_country' and period='0' AND end_time =
>   end_time_date('2014-01-12')

Based on documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/, i don't know why i have to specify end_time when period is 0:

[image]

However, this query would return the total likes of each country, so you can simply sum the total.

**Page id 53829903566  (http://www.facebook.com/fiatdk):**
[image]

**Page id 110630838997361  (http://www.facebook.com/fiatnl):**
[image]

Note: end_time_date('2014-01-12'), you cannot do end_time_date('2014-01-13') because it return empty results, so you may consider adjust a bit the current date:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right that the likes are combined. But the question is how I can check the actual likes for every individual Facebook child page with the Graph API explorer. We know that Facebook collects and shows the Facebook likes seperately for each page. You can even see the actual likes if you are a child page administrator.

Comment: @user3197223 i've update my answer, can you check it out and make sure the total is nearly match(i'm not child page administrator)?